# Makefile pattern for 1:1 recipe with a prerequisite that differs from target in both directory and file extension

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

For each `.md` file underneath a directory called `src`, I want to generate an HTML file underneath a new directory `pub` with the same internal directory structure, e.g.

```
src/foo/hello.md -> pub/foo/hello.html
src/bar/world.md -> pub/bar/world.html
```

I'm stuck on writing the prerequisites for each html file. Here's what I have so far:

```
SRCS = $(shell find src -name "*.md")
HTML = $(subst src/,pub/,$(SRCS:.md=.html))

%.html: %.md
    @echo "placeholder to generate $@ from $<"

publish: $(HTML)
```

As written, I get

```
$ make publish
make: *** No rule to make target `pub/foo/hello.html', needed by `publish'.  Stop.
```

If I remove the prerequisites like this:

```
%.html: %.md
    @echo "placeholder to generate $@ from $<"
```

then I get:

```
$ make publish
placeholder to generate pub/foo/hello.html from 
placeholder to generate pub/bar/world.html from
```

which is closer, but does not handle the prerequisite Markdown file.

How do I write a pattern for the prerequisite with both differing root directory *and* extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write the prefix and the suffix in the pattern:

```
pub/%.html : src/%.md
        ...
```